# how do I make a java program to check if there is a vowel in a string?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a program that check a string if there is at least one vowel in the string. But when I input a string that have a vowel in it, the result is ""your password word is not acceptable" instead of "your password word is acceptable".

can someone show me where I do wrong? thank you!

here is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class checker {
    static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password;
        System.out.println("enter your password:");
        password= input.next();
        String vowel[]= {"a","e","i","o","u"};
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            boolean check[] = new boolean[5];
            check[i]=password.contains(vowel[i]);
             if(i==vowel.length-1&&check[0] ==false && check[1]==false && check[2]==false && check[3]==false && check[4]==false) {
                System.out.println("your password word is not acceptable");
             }else System.out.println("your password is acceptable");
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think this happens? Have you tried using a debugger and tracing your program to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: This would be much easier using a regex.

Comment: That's pretty difficult, since 'y' can sometimes be a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class checker {
    static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password;
        System.out.println("enter your password:");
        password= input.next();
        String vowel[]= {"a","e","i","o","u"};
        boolean check = false;
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            check = password.toLowercase().contains(vowel[i]);
            if(check){ 
                break; 
            }
       }
             if(!check){
                System.out.println("your password word is not acceptable");
             }else {
                System.out.println("your password is acceptable");
             }
      }
 }
```

Comment: This potentially suffers from an assumption in the OP's code that the entered vowel would be lower case. Also, "y" can be a vowel, but that might be over complicating things.

Comment: @KevinO - Your first point is taken care. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check if a string contains vowel or not using regular expression.Please check the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "tssta";
    String regex= ".*[AEIOUaeiou].*";
    if(input.matches(regex)){
        System.out.println("your password word is acceptable");
    }else {
        System.out.println("your password word is not acceptable");
    }
}
```